# Why can't find package required on the "npm" registry

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

I have problems running my web app using this tutorial video [React Native Web Full App Tutorial - Build a Workout App for iOS, Android, and Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CBYbEGvxYY)
 in react-native. I've been searching a lot for an answer but there is no accurate one yet that solves my issue.

I downloaded the app from here: [git repo](https://github.com/benawad/react-native-web-series).

Try to use:

```
$ yarn
$ yarn install
$ npm install
$ npm config set @icons:registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm i https://github.com/Qix-/node-error-ex
$ curl 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/node/-/node-9.4.2.tgz'
```

but nothing seems to work, I keep getting this error.

```
error Couldn't find package "@wow/common@1.0.0" required by "@wow/app@0.0.1" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Couldn't find package "@wow/common@1.0.0" required by "react-native-web-workout-series@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Or any steps I need to follow to run this app. Since I want to download the app and edit the body content.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason was the `.npmrc` file.

You can rename this file

```
mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc2

npx create-react-app my-app
```

and rename it back after the installation.

```
mv ~/.npmrc2 ~/.npmrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to download and test it myself and it worked normally.

Clone it again and follow these steps:

```sh
#After cloning enter the folder
cd react-native-web-series
#install all dependencies
yarn install
#Navigate to the web folder
cd packages/web
#start the app
yarn start
```

Ps. : If a project is using yarn is not a good ideia to run `npm` commands, do not mix those two

Comment: Thank for your kind reply. Yes, after your post I achieve to run the project. But I am making one of my own also, and I can't figure out why that error seems to appear.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is checking if you have the latest version of yarn and run `yarn install`, or `yarn add wow-common`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem here.
And just as @Dmitry Grinko mentioned, it is related to .npmrc file.

I used private npm registry before so that some of package is missing.

Using following registry will pass the problem.

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: For Macos/linux users I had to add the registry to `$HOME/.npmrc`

Answer (score 1):

use `npm login` in terminal to login into your npm registry.

More information available here:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6029

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your npmrc file (on /Users/:username)

```
always-auth=true
```

Answer (score 0):

- npm install -g npm@latest
- npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

If you're using nvm

- nvm install 14.18.0
- nvm use 14.18.0

---

nvm alias default 14.18.0

Answer (score 0):

for those who run into this error when using yarn workspaces, i was able to resolve this by adding a `.yarnrc` file with the following contents

```
//{your_registry}/:always-auth=true
registry=https://{your_registry}/
```

to **each** package and the root directory

Answer (score -1):

after look on the git repo - i think that maybe you should try to run npm i (or other commands - im not from react native area) in any package(app,common,web) to itself - like I saw any one of them has package.json of his own

Comment: Sorry didn't get it  quite well